# How can I use an IF statement in view to show one of two tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to have an IF statement within my view to show one of two tables depending on the result passed to the View. My code at the moment only shows one table:

```
<div>
    Date From: <%: Model.DateFrom%>
    <br />
    Date To: <%: Model.DateTo%>
    <br />
    Report Type: <%: Model.ReportType%>
</div>
    <table class="sorted-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Tickets Created</th>
                <th>Tickets Resolved</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <%
        Dim oResult As Object
        For Each oResult In Model.ReportResults
            Response.Write("<tr>")
            Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ClientName & "</td>")
            Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.CreatedCount & "</td>")
            Response.Write("<td>" & oResult.ResolvedCount & "</td>")
            Response.Write("</tr>")
        Next


    %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like to have a similar table, using the report type once it's passed it. If it returns the value of 1 then I would like it to display the current table but if it returns 2 then I would like it to display a similar table that I can create. Can anybody point me in the right direction for this please?

Comment: why don't you do this server side? It'll probably be faster (you could even redirect to action if need be)

Comment: I have done the calculations server side. I would just like an If statement that displays the correct tables in accordance to the returned value. I'm just returning the results to the view

Comment: Either use jquery/javascript, or ajax depending on your situation.